# Is it true that Prince Charles can be bypassed in the line of succession?

Tags: politics, united-kingdom

This [source](http://royalcentral.co.uk/blogs/insight/can-prince-charles-be-skipped-in-the-line-of-succession-22445) posits that the succession to the British throne is ultimately in the hands of the Parliament, not the queen or royal family.

The news source considers an important counter argument to bypass Prince Charles in the succession, that even though he (re-) married a divorced woman, Lady Camilla Parker Bowles, he has a lot more experience as a royal than his son and daughter in law, and would therefore make a better monarch.

The British government was an important factor in the abdication of King Edward VIII because of his marriage to Wallace Simpson. Could it, in theory, step in to prevent the ascension, or cause the early abdication of King Charles III, even though it is not likely to do so?

Comment: Starting point for reading about this is [Succession to the British throne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succession_to_the_British_throne) which points to the laws and history.

Comment: Another starting point might be the linked article itself that explains why the rumour is without merit.

Comment: First, Edward VIII was not *legally* forced to abdicate. He was essentially persuaded to abdicate to prevent a constitutional crisis. Similarly Charles could not be *forced* to abdicate. The issue with Edward VIII was two-fold - that divorce was not permitted at the time in the Church of England (of which Edward and Charles were/will be heads) and the general acceptability of divorce. Both those situations have changed enormously since 1936.

Comment: @TomAu: Ah, if that is the substance of the question, it needs to be closed. There will be some pressure for him to resign for a multitude of reasons. (I will add my voice to the mix, for his unskeptical and unethical views of medicine.) However, we can't know if whether he would choose to do so - it would be pure speculation.

Comment: @TomAu "Peer pressure" <-- I see what you did there.

Comment: Wow, you totally changed the question, which isn't good practice. The new question is also opinion-based. It is not one that can be determined by empirical evidence - it is a question of royal politics.

Comment: @Oddthinking: OK, rolled it back to the original. Thought that the newer, related, version would be more acceptable, but that apparently isn't the case.

Comment: The question as expressed in the title seems to be acceptable, i.e. Is there a mechanism by which the Queen could cause Charles to be bypassed in favor of Prince William?  This is certainly a different question than what is asked in the body of the question, which is just a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Oddthinking: Followed Mark's suggestion to ask about a "legal mechanism," in the last sentence which is more objective. Is the question ok now?

Comment: Related question on Politics.SE: [Why was Edward VIII's marriage a problem, but not Prince Charles's?](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/9056/why-was-edward-viiis-marriage-a-problem-but-not-prince-charless/)

Comment: Please find a clear, precise and notable claim. This question seems to be about a personal curiosity rather than a notable claim.

Comment: As Sklivvz notes, the question is still lacking a notable claim.  Here's a source stating that Parliament could change the line of succession and skip over Prince Charles.  Perhaps that will do.  http://royalcentral.co.uk/blogs/insight/can-prince-charles-be-skipped-in-the-line-of-succession-22445

Comment: @Mark: I used your link. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Sklivvz: I used Mark's more objective link. Is the question better now?

Comment: Okay, so the claim now is: "While Prince Charles is next in line for the throne, the Parliament could totally change the laws of the land, so he isn't." This seems a vacuous claim. They *could* also get rid of the monarchy. They *could* also declare the moderators of Skeptics.SE to be Heads of Government. How can this question be answered by evidence?

Comment: The question in the title is "Is it true that Prince Charles can be bypassed in the line of succession?"  The answer appears to be "The Queen cannot do this.  The only way would be for Prince Charles to abdicate or for Parliament to change the succession laws."  That answer needs a referenced source.